# How do i display a message box if the textbox is empty after a search

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access

I'm trying to display a message box if no data is pulled from the database at the end of the comparison

```css
Private Sub submitbutton_Click(sender As Object,
e As EventArgs) Handles submitbutton.Click myConnection.Open()
 tutorboxr.Clear()
 compboxr.Clear()
 Dim str As String
 Dim etr As String
 str="SELECT * FROM 2014Results WHERE (Competitor = '" & Competitor.Text &"')"
 etr="SELECT * FROM 2014Results WHERE (Event = '" & EventBox.Text &"')"
 
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand=New OleDbCommand(str,
myConnection) 

Dim emd As OleDbCommand=New OleDbCommand(etr,
myConnection) dr=cmd.ExecuteReader

While dr.Read() 
compboxr.Text=dr("Rank").ToString 
textbox.Text=dr("Reg").ToString

If Competitor.Text="" Then MessageBox.Show("This student wasn't a ranking placeholder!",
MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Error) 
End If 
End While myConnection.Close() 

If Competitor.Text="" Then MessageBox.Show("Please enter a students name",
"No entry",
MessageBoxButtons.OK,
MessageBoxIcon.Error) With Competitor .Focus() .SelectAll() End With Exit Sub 
End If
End Sub
```

I receive this error:

> Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Show' can be called without a narrowing conversion:   : Argument matching parameter narrows from 'MessageBoxButtons' to 'String'.   : Argument matching parameter narrows from to 'MessageBoxButtons'.   : Argument matching parameter narrows from 'String' to.   : Argument matching parameter 'text' narrows from 'MessageBoxButtons' to 'String'.   : Argument matching parameter narrows from to 'String'.

Comment: Turn option strict on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a parameter on the first `MessageBox.Show` call:

```
If Competitor.Text="" Then
    MessageBox.Show("This student wasn't a ranking placeholder!",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error) 
End If
```

It should be like the second call:

```
If Competitor.Text="" Then
    MessageBox.Show("This student wasn't a ranking placeholder!",
                    "** a caption here **",
                    MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                    MessageBoxIcon.Error) 
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, the error is now no longer there! But I'm testing the program and even when i purposely enter false details the program wont display the message box

Comment: Actually you were right, everything is working now. Thanks